# restricting access to a public setter

Tags: encapsulation, typescript, access-control, setters

My question is how I can achieve more encapsulation in TypeScript.

I have a class `Item`, with a public setter `isOwned`, but I only want to call this method in specific situations: if the item is picked up or dropped by a `Player`.

```
/** @package A */
class Item {
    private _is_owned: boolean = false

    // ...

    /** @returns - Has this item been picked up by a player? */
    get isOwned(): boolean {
        return this._is_owned
    }

    /** @param owned - Is a player picking up this item? */
    set isOwned(owned: boolean) {
        this._is_owned = owned
    }
}

/** @package B */
class Player {
    private _items: Set<Item> = new Set()

    // ...

    /**
     * @param item - the item in question
     * @returns - Does this player own the item?
     */
    owns(item: Item): boolean {
        return this._items.has(item)
    }

    /**
     * @param item - the item to pick up
     * @throws - if the item is already owned
     */
    pickUp(item: Item): void {
        if (item.isOwned) throw new Error('cannot pick up item that is already owned')
        this._items.add(item)
        item.isOwned = true // WARNING public method
    }

    /**
     * @param item - the item to drop
     * @throws - if this player does not own the item
     */
    drop(item: Item): void {
        if (!this.owns(item)) throw new Error('cannot drop item that player does not own')
        this._items.delete(item)
        item.isOwned = false // WARNING public method
    }
}
```

The methods `Player#pickUp` and `Player#drop` need to check the ownership of an item to determine whether the player is allowed to pick up or drop the item. So in those methods, the setter `Item#isOwned` is called, and therefore it needs to be public. (In TypeScript, there is no such thing as package-private, and even if there were, `Player` and `Item` are not in the same package.)

I want that setter to be called *only* in those methods though, because there are security implications: Since `Item#isOwned` is public, a “hacker” could bypass the checks before the `#pickUp` and `#drop` methods, as so:

```
/**
 * Allow a player to pick up an item,
 * even if that item is owned by another player.
 */
function hack(player1: Player, player2: Player, item: Item): void {
    player1.pickUp(item)
    try {
        player2.pickUp(item)
    } catch (e) {
        item.isOwned = false // <!-- this is very bad
        player2.pickUp(item)
    }
}
```

I’ve tried moving the methods to the `Item` class, but that won’t work because the methods need to access the private field `Player#_items`.

Then I tried separating each method into two: one in class `Player` where the item is added/deleted to the player, and another in class `Item` where ownership is tested, but that gives the same problem (just with different method names).

It seems like no matter what I do, getting/setting the ownership of an item needs to be public, so any program that calls `Player#pickUp` and `Player#drop` will also be able to get/set the item’s ownership status.

So how do I solve this problem? Is there a different data structure I need to use, or do I need to rethink my entire strategy?

Comment: *"I want that setter to be called only in those methods though, because there are security implications"* - You should not confuse encapsulation and security. They are completely orthogonal concepts. Making something `private` or `public` does not affect security in any way that matters.

Comment: Perhpas you are checking whether a player can pick up an item too late when you are already in Player#pickup. On the other hand, "actions" are not always something Player have to know how to do, Actions can be another class "ItemPickUp" which solves the indirection between the two. Here you can place validations or moreover, validate the action against the server information to enforce security and consistency (if there's any ofc)

Answer (score 1):

For a little bit more control over the ownership of the item, you could store **who** owns the item instead of storing that the item **is** owned.

I'm not familiar with the syntax, so here's some pseudocode.

```
class Player
{
  List<item> items;

  public void Pickup(item)
  {
    var newItem = item.PickedUpBy(this);
    if(newItem != null)
    {
      world.replaceItem(item, newItem); // assuming you have a place were the original item came from
      items.add(newItem);
    }
  }

  public void Drop(item)
  {
    var newItem = item.DroppedBy(this);
    if(newItem != null)
    {
      items.remove(item);
      world.replaceItem(item, newItem);
    }
  }
}

class Item
{
  private Player owner;

  public Item PickedUpBy(Player player)
  {
    if(owner != null)
    {
      // Item is owned, cannot pickup
      return null;
    }
    Item newItem = new Item(....);
    newItem.owner = player;
    return newItem;
  }

  public Item DroppedBy(Player player)
  {
    if(player != owner)
    {
      // Throw hacker error
    }
    Item newItem = new Item(....);
    newItem.owner = null;
    return newItem;
  }
}
```

However, if a hacker can execute code, like in your example, this will not prevent them from manipulating objects in memory.

Comment: “if a hacker can execute code” - ideally, a hacker couldn’t execute code, but it’s more of a complaint that the code is permissible. e.g. nothing to prevent my future self from executing it.

Comment: i'm confused by what your code does. could you please add some comments? it looks like every time a player picks up an item, a whole new item is constructed?

Comment: Correct, that concept is called immutability. I'd gladly explain other parts, anything specific?

Comment: i'm not sure that fits my model. say i create a new item, `spoon`, and at first it has no owner. then `player1.pickUp(spoon)` should give it an owner, to prevent `player2` from picking it up. in your code though, a new spoon is created every time, so you could have an unlimited number of players picking up the spoon … not the exact same spoon, but an identical spoon. in my model, there is only one spoon (unless we're in the Matrix, in which case there is no spoon). any new spoons would need to be constructed separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C++ by declaring a friend class or even just a friend function, and in Swift by declaring a fileprivate setter which can only be used in that file.

In many languages you could have a setter with a second parameter saying who asks for the value to be changed, where you have to pass in the caller and the compiler does the type checking; the setter should check that the value passed is not nil. Of course a caller can get around this if it has a reference to any object of the right class, but then nothing is bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

If the decision that something is "owned" is based on whether some external object holds a reference to it, then I think a public boolean setter represents very different semantics than what you intend.

Instead, I'd consider a method like "TakeOwnership(parent)" and use it to store a reference. Then remove the public setter, and simply have business logic in your IsOwned() getter that determines whether the parent reference is still valid.

Getters don't have to represent a field; they can contain business logic; that's part of the value of abstracting them as a getter instead of publicly exposing the field.

One of the tradeoffs in exposing public setters is that, while convenient for initially populating values, you risk accidental complexity due to the [Law of Demeter](https://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter). If allowing external code to change your state isn't what you want, you don't need to.

An alternative, depending on how your object lifetimes end up working, might be to store a reference to a OwnershipRoster, which could contain mappings between objects capable of owning things and the things that they own, and defer IsOwned implementation to that.